# Javascript - Replace '%20' spaces

Tags: javascript, dom, replace

```
var loc_array = document.location.href.split('/');
var linkElement = document.getElementById("waBackButton");
var newT = document.createTextNode(loc_array[loc_array.length-2]); 
var repl = newT.replace('%20',' ');
linkElement.appendChild(repl);
```

Anyone know why this causes the text to not show up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just do

```
unescape(document.location.href);
```

Comment: Where would that go though. I have .split() on the end.

Comment: I would unescape the string before you split it. Understand that if you use .split('\') on document.location.href, you are going to get some empty elements. Your array will look something like: 
`['http:','','www.someplace.com','dir1','subdir1','afile.htm?foo=bar&spork=spoon+fork']`