# Jquery replace characters

Tags: jquery, replace

in the next examples :

```
 <b id="TITLE">The%20Vampire%20Diaries</b>

 <b id="TITLE"> How%20I%20met%20your%20moom</b>
```

how can i replace all `%20` with `" "`(space) in all the names that a contained in `id="TITle"` ?

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - Replace '%20' spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215022/javascript-replace-20-spaces)

Comment: BTW, id should be unique

Answer (score 4):

Use [`unescape()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dz4x90hk%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
$("#TITLE").text(function(i,v){
    return unescape(v);
});
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rm8GU/1*

---

FYI: In case both elements in your example exist in the same document, ID should be unique, and you should use class references instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have 2 items with the same ID. Try using a class instead, then iterating the classes.

```
$('.TITLE').each(function(){

    $(this).text(unescape($(this).text()));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#TITLE").text($("#TITLE").text().replace("%20", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('b').each(function (i) {
if ($(this).id=='Title');
{ $(this).text($(this).text().replace("%20", " "));

}
});
```